# Squish gets the wrong QML type (the base type instead of the actual type)

Tags: qml, squish

I added a new base type to some existing QML code and changed some other types to derive from it. I then moved the properties of those other types into the base type. Now Squish thinks instances of the derived types are instances of the base type. Is this a bug in Squish, and if so, is there a workaround? I could change my test code to look for objects of the base type instead, but that doesn't seem like the right solution really.

Comment: you have to provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of explain the code.

Comment: That's easier said than done unfortunately. This isn't my project and I don't have the expertise with Squish yet to know how to setup my own test environment. I was hoping somebody else had seen something similar with their tests. I've discovered that if I add a dummy property to the derived types, Squish works properly again. So, it seems to have something to do with the fact that my derived types now have no properties of their own (they only have child objects).

Comment: I recommend to contact the vendor of the tool, as that has the best chances to quickly clarify whether there is a bug or if this is simply not supported or something else going on there.